# OpenshiftV3 Adding Docker Images from external Repository

Tags: docker-registry, openshift-origin

I am new to OpenshiftV3 and I am just wondering if it's possible to add all images or sync openshift with images in an external docker-registry.

Example : All docker images found in https://registry.somehost.com can be visible in my openshift project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible today to synchronize an entire registry - you'll need to do it repo by repo using "oc import-image foo --all --confirm"